# React-i18next init callback resolving before Suspense resolves

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next, react-suspense

Using react-i18next with Suspense.

I want to use the init callback option to run an [axios interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to ensure all requests add the correct header language.

My problem is that the init callback doesn't halt the Suspense to render its children. I thought returning a promise from init would work but it doesn't.

Is halting the Suspense to resolve possible?

My code:

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init(
    {
      lng: 'en',
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      debug: true,
      react: {
        wait: true,
      },
    },
    function callback() {
      // this is the place where I want to halt Suspense until my logic is done

      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        i18nInterceptor(i18n.language);
        setTimeout(() => {
          res();
        }, 10000);
      });
    }
  );

export default i18n;
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, my 'solution' was not to use Suspense. Maybe I should give it a new try...